# radiobutton checked status on asp:linkbutton postback

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-2.0

I have four radiobuttons inside a repeater control which  by itself is inside an update panel

// code is something like this

```
`<asp:update panel ..>
...
<asp:Repeater>
..
<asp:checkbox>
..
..
</asp:update panel ..>
<asp:LinkButton ID="next2" runat="server" CssClass="button_Submit" Font-Bold="true"    OnClick="next_ServerClick" Text="Submit"> 
<asp:ImageButton ID="next" ImageUrl="~/images/newSummary.jpg" runat="server" OnClick="next_ServerClick" ImageAlign="Middle"/>
protected void next_ServerClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
foreach (System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterItem Item in repeatercontrol.Items)
{
   chkbox = ((CheckBox)Item.FindControl(chkboxName));
   if (chkbox.checked)
   {
    ...
   }
}
}`
```

I select one of the checkboxes and when i click image button, am able to get the correct status (checked =true) .

But when i use link button, it is always coming as checked =false as if the selection did not register.

Any ideas on why this is happening?

Comment: Can you post your code-behind where you are doing this checking for both the ImageButton and LinkButton?

Comment: I was asking for the code around the checking for the loop. ie: the events for the ImageButton and LinkButton.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking about. Are you asking abt the eventhandler for the onclick event. 

protected void linkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // code above
}

Answer (score 0):

You need to register the linkbutton click event as a trigger in the update panel. See example below:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" >
    <ContentTemplate>

        ...

    </ContentTemplate>

    <Triggers>

        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="LinkButtonID" EventName="Click" />

    </Triggers>

</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it still did not work.
As I have mentioned, I am able to get value when I use Image button (and it is not added as a trigger)

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the code, the only reason the controls would be incorrect is if you are checking them in the [Page Life Cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) before the [ViewState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.viewstate.aspx) is loaded.

EDIT:
Use separate event declarations and centralize the lookup logic:

```
    protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void ImageButton1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Comment: I am checking the values in the onclick event handler for the buttons. So, Viewstate should have been loaded by then, correct ?

Comment: Yes, it should be there in those events.

Comment: I know i keep asking, but it would be helpful to see how you declare these events and the actual code-behind.  Things like this tend to be simple oversight.

Comment: //declaration code
<asp:LinkButton ID="next2" runat="server" CssClass="button_Submit" Font-Bold="true" OnClick="next_ServerClick" Text="Submit">

<asp:ImageButton ID="next" ImageUrl="~/Includes/images/newSummary.jpg"                       runat="server" OnClick="next_ServerClick" ImageAlign="Middle"/>

// event handler
protected void linkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { // code above }